# PHP foreach value replaced in associative array

Tags: php, foreach

how is your day? 
Mine is not so good because I can't seem to figure it out. I have a form that looks like this:

```
<body>
<form action = "opdracht4.7.test.php" method="get">
    Uw naam: <input type="text" name="naam"><br>
    Uw e-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <br>
    Bevalt deze website? <input type="radio" name="keuze" value="Ja" checked> Ja
        <input type="radio" name="keuze" value="Nee"> Nee
        <input type="radio" name="keuze" value="Weet niet"> Weet niet <br>
    <br>
    Uw commentaar: <br>
    <textarea name="commentaar"></textarea><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

To process the data I have some requirements that are in a function:

```
function check_input($input) {
    $input = htmlspecialchars($input);
    $input = trim($input);
    $input = stripslashes($input);

    return $input;
}
```

Now I use $_GET to get all information:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $form = array($_GET['naam'], $_GET['email'], $_GET['keuze'], $_GET['commentaar']);
```

so everything is working fine, now I use:

```
foreach($form as $key => $value) {
        $value = check_input($value);
        echo $key.' is a '.$value."<br>";
    }
```

But here is where it goes wrong. Every value that passes through $_GET['x'] must be replaced with check_input($value)... But it does not work. The values in the loop are changed but if I quit the foreach loop the $values are still not trimmed, nor adjusted. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for your `$form` array, but mapped against your `check_input` function:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $form = array($_GET['naam'], $_GET['email'], $_GET['keuze'], $_GET['commentaar']);
    $form = array_map('check_input', $form);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here $value must be stored in array defined outside the block foreach loop like below

```
$value=array();
$i=0;
foreach($form as $key => $value) {
    $value[$i] = check_input($value);
    echo $key.' is a '.$value[$i]."<br>";
$i++; 
  }
 print_r($value);
```